# Jest: awaiting inside a setInterval prevents setTimeout from being called

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I am trying to mock a setTimeout inside of a setInterval with Jest, but am seeing confusing behavior and I do not know whether it is a bug, or if I am doing something wrong.

Awaiting inside the async function passed to setInterval causes setTimeout to never run. If I remove the await in the function below, the setTimeout is successfully set.

```
jest.setTimeout(10000);

let interval;

/**
 * Check for a promise to return true before clearing an interval and setting a timeout
 * @param {boolean} shouldAwaitRes - toggle whether to await inside the async callback
 * @param {function} callback - mock function to call inside timeout
 */
const check = async (shouldAwaitRes, callback) => {
  const res = shouldAwaitRes ? await Promise.resolve(true) : Promise.resolve(true);

  if (res) {
    clearInterval(interval);

    setTimeout(() => {
      callback();
    }, 2000);
  }
};

/**
 * Set an interval with an async function that awaits a response
 * @param {boolean} shouldAwaitRes - toggle whether to await inside the async callback
 * @param {function} callback - mock function to pass into set timeout
 */
const setAsyncInterval = async (shouldAwaitRes, callback) => {
  interval = setInterval(check, 1000, shouldAwaitRes, callback);
};

/**
 * Wait 6 seconds for real timers to run
 */
const pause = async () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 6000);
  });
};

// ----------------------------------
// Tests

describe('Timers', () => {
  let callback;
  beforeEach(() => {
    callback = jest.fn();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });

  describe('No Fake Timers Used', () => {
    it('should call the callback inside the async setInterval callback when awaiting', async done => {
      await setAsyncInterval(true, callback); // setting to true to await inside async callback

      // Pause 6 seconds to let the timers runs
      await pause();

      expect(callback).toBeCalled(); // callback is called

      done();
    });
  });

  describe('Fake Timers', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      jest.useFakeTimers();
    });

    afterEach(() => {
      jest.clearAllTimers();
    });

    it('should call the callback inside the async setInterval callback when NOT awaiting', async done => {
      await setAsyncInterval(false, callback); // setting to false to disable awaiting inside async callback

      // Advance Time 6 seconds
      jest.advanceTimersByTime(6000);

      expect(callback).toBeCalled(); // callback is called

      done();
    });

    // The below test fails
    it('should call the callback inside the async setInterval callback when awaiting', async done => {
      await setAsyncInterval(true, callback); // setting to true to enable awaiting inside async callback

      // Advance Time 6 seconds
      jest.advanceTimersByTime(6000);

      expect(callback).toBeCalled(); // callback is NOT called

      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Also reported to Jest to see if it might be a bug: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9181

Edit: updated sample reproduction cases and added Jest Issue

Comment: Apparently the fake timers don't expect the `setInterval` callback to do asynchronous stuff. And that's probably reasonable, since there is no way how they could wait for it, and look whether another timer will be scheduled.

Comment: The only way to "fix" this bug would be to have the fake timers also synchronously run microtasks (promise callbacks), which they cannot.

Comment: Not sure how clear you are about what the actual problem is. If not, try rewriting the code without `async function`s and use plain promise `then` instead in `check` - it will exhibit the same behaviour.

Comment: What does your actual code look like? Having `async function`s as callbacks and timeout-cleared intervals looks very much like antipatterns. Maybe you could solve this by improving your code so that you wouldn't run into this problem at all.

Comment: Oh whoops. That was a typo in my haste, updated the original question with a clearer reproduction case.

Comment: Where did you find a typo? I can't see much of a difference between the original and the updated code - except the original was shorter and a bit simpler to understand imo.